# Styling corners Duo drawer navigation menu in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm working on a project using Duo Navigation Drawer, and I want the edges of the Linear Layout to be rounded when the menu is opened. How can I achieve this?

I tried with shape on the linear layout but i have an image in the background

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.